# nfs nlockmgr timed out

Tags: nfs

thanks for reading me and helping me !

I got a NFS problem. It's not a permanent problem it comes and goes.
Sometimes (very often), the clients using the mounted partitions are frozen when they're trying to open a new program like eclipse or kde.
I think it's a lock problem due to maybe a network problem or optimization problem, but I don't know what to do, I tried a lot of thing but I failed....

The ubuntu version

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

When Everything is OK :

```
Every 2.0s: rpcinfo -u 10.10.10.2 nlockmgr              Wed Jan  9 13:50:41 2013
rpcinfo: RPC: Program/version mismatch; low version = 1, high version = 4program
 100021 version 1 ready and waiting
program 100021 version 2 is not available
program 100021 version 3 ready and waiting
program 100021 version 4 ready and waiting
```

When the problem happens

> Every 2.0s: rpcinfo -u 10.10.10.X nlockmgr              Wed Jan  9
>   13:58:39 2013
>   rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out
>   program 100021 version 0 is not available

No problem with others like mountd or status

Server log :

> Jan  9 14:02:25 dallas kernel: [95801.650031] statd: server rpc.statd
>   not responding, timed out Jan  9 14:02:25 dallas kernel:
>   [95801.650044] lockd: cannot monitor topalbum

client log :

> kernel: lockd: server 10.10.10.X not responding, timed out
>
> Jan  9 13:22:24 topalbum kernel: [6464607.366966] lockd: server
>   fileserver OK Jan  9 13:23:24 topalbum kernel: [6464667.367109] lockd:
>   server fileserver OK Jan  9 13:24:24 topalbum kernel: [6464727.520031]
>   lockd: server fileserver not responding, still trying Jan  9 13:24:24
>   topalbum kernel: [6464727.520115] lockd: server fileserver not
>   responding, still trying
>
> avahi-daemon[3890]: Invalid query packet.

I tried to increase the RPCNFSDCOUNT in /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server using

> echo "512" > /proc/fs/nfsd/threads

I tried to mount client partitions with no lock, tcp....

I tested the network performance with iperf, got 936 Go/s

I got statd enabled

server is up to date

I am exhausted...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a direct answer but it'll probably help someone: I had the same problem and symptoms as soon as some of the client systems were upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 (running 3.8 kernel), on two different NFS servers running different kernels.